# Is final variable changing its value throughout time?

Tags: java, final

I'm currently teaching myself Java from a textbook, and found a piece of code that I don't understand - why does the final variable `id` change it's value?

```
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;
class Shared {
    private int refcount = 0;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int id = counter++;
    public Shared() {
        print("Creating " + this);
    }
    public void addRef() { refcount++; }
    protected void dispose() {
        if(--refcount == 0)
            print("Disposing " + this);
    }
    protected void finalize() {
        if(refcount != 0)
            print("Error: object is not properly cleaned-up!");
    }
    public String toString() { return "Shared " + id; }
}
class Composing {
    private Shared shared;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int id = counter++;
    public Composing(Shared shared) {
        print("Creating " + this);
        this.shared = shared;
        this.shared.addRef();
    }
    protected void dispose() {
        print("disposing " + this);
        shared.dispose();
    }
    public String toString() { return "Composing " + id; }
}
public class E13_VerifiedRefCounting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared shared = new Shared();
        Composing[] composing = { new Composing(shared),
                new Composing(shared), new Composing(shared),
                new Composing(shared), new Composing(shared) };
        for(Composing c : composing)
            c.dispose();
```

Comment: Why do you say that the id variable is final?

Comment: I just copy - pasted the code from not translated version of the book and there was a id variable without final prefix (what?) so I changed it to be final as it is in my version of this book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int id = counter++;
    public Shared() {
        print("Creating " + this);
    }
```

is the same as this:

```
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int id;
    public Shared() {
        id = counter++;
        print("Creating " + this);
    }
```

That is, the `id` is assigned every time the constructor executes, with the side effect that `counter` is incremented.

`id` is an instance variable, so each instance of `shared` gets its own `id` value.

Comment: heres the code from the original code from the book https://ibb.co/ZxcYZ6X?fbclid=IwAR0ZUM26YaJijk_6qOxOf2P2Z8hsu9p8Ro--Rnn9agsFG7Y3WQe7uM_tMiA

Comment: so my guess is that the final placed there is just a mistake?

Comment: No, `final` means the variable a) has to be assigned in the ctor, b) can't be reassigned in or after the ctor.

Comment: It's not a mistake, it's working correctly

Comment: ooookay -  id initialization in the constructor is way clearer for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
private final int id = counter++;
```

If by change you are asking why does the value of `id` is `counter + 1` instead of just `counter`, that's because first the sum `counter + 1` is calculated, and then it is set into `id`. After that, the value of id cannot change.

Comment: but the *old* value of `counter` is set into `id`